# Connection between two NXT bricks

Tags: nxt, nxc

Is it possible send information from BrickNXT_A to BrickNXTB_B?

For example I have a touch sensor connected to IN_1 of Brick_A and I want send the result of the sensor status (1 or 0) to Brick_B. If the touch sensor status on IN_1 of brick_A is 1, then the motor connected with OUT_A in brick_B, turn for 1 rotation.

How to do this with NXC? My difficult is the connection and sending information between the Bricks.

Comment: A long time ago in an university club we once managed to hack an RCX cable into an RCX compatible LED, built a frame to mount it into a LEGO structure, wrapped a clear flexible plastic "wire" in tinfoil and duct tape (to minimise light loss) and built another LEGO structure for the other end that held an NXT light sensor. After a bit of programming we could send information from the RCX to the NXT via the optical cable. the only downside was the speed: we could only manage about 1 bit per second. Maybe someone could improve on this concept?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Have a look at the "Comm module functions" section of the NXT help file. For example, since the touch sensor status is a boolean value, you could use the SendRemoteBool and ReceiveRemoteBool functions. You can communicate wirelessly using the Bluetooth functions (BT*) or you can have a wired connection using RS485 by connecting input port 4 on each brick to each other.